# Validation on my HTML form in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have a username form. Which have 2 fields, username and password. Basically users have been trying to put their email address in to login, which is a pain because I only want them to log in with their username and not email.

So I'm needing it so if a user tried to put their email address in the username field, it will display an error like "Use your username, not email to login". Below the field.
E.g.

If the user puts in "myemail@test.com" in the field and presses submit, then the error will appear.

I currently have a 'required field' validation on too at the moment.

Here is the code:

JS:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
  function validar()
  {
     var right = 1;

     if(document.getElementById('email').value.length==0)
     {
        right = 0;
        document.getElementById('emptymail').innerHTML = "Fill in the required fields";
     }
     if(document.getElementById('password').value.length==0)
     {
        right = 0;
        document.getElementById('emptypass').innerHTML = "Fill in the required fields";
     }

    if(right == 1)
    {
      document.forms["formu"].submit();
    }

  }
  </script>
```

FORM:

```
<div id="sessionContainer" class="clearfix">
  <div class="content">
     <form action="goto.php" class=" sign-in" method="post" name="formu" id="formu">
      <div style="margin:0;padding:0"></div>
      <h3>Please login</h3>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <label for="">Username</label><br>
        <input class="xlarge" id="email" name="email" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" /><div id="emptymail"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <label for=""><br>
          Password</label><br>
        <input class="xlarge" id="password" name="password" tabindex="2" type="password" value="" /><div id="emptypass"></div>
      </div>


      <p class="remember">&nbsp;</p>
      <p class="remember">
        <button class="btn btn-m btn-blue" id="signin_submit" name="commit" type="button" tabindex=5 onclick="validar();">Sign in</button>
      </p>
```

Thanks

Comment: does the username allow the character `@`? because it seems like you could just check for the existence of that in the string with .indexOf() > -1

Comment: Well all usernames are characters and numbers, but I'd prefer it if it was possible to validate it within the email format

Comment: Where exactly are you getting stuck? Detecting wrong input and detecting empty input are very similar tasks, so you seem to be most of the way there already.

Comment: Are you saying you want to detect it as an email address so you can say, "Don't use your email address?"

Comment: What happens if the user registered with their email address for username? They won't be able to login.

Comment: @IMSoP Not sure how to implement the email address thing.

Comment: @J.D.Pace Yes correct

Comment: @SomeSillyName The registration form says username only now. so people don't register with their email

Comment: Seems like a search for "detect email address javascript" or "validate email address javascript" would be your best bet then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it's brilliant naming a username field that should not contain an e-mail address "email".
Anyway.

```
function validar()
{
    if(document.getElementById('email').value.length==0)
    {
       document.getElementById('emptymail').innerHTML = "Fill in the required fields";
       return;
    }
    if(document.getElementById('password').value.length==0)
    {
       document.getElementById('emptypass').innerHTML = "Fill in the required fields";
       return;
    }
    var x=document.getElementById('email').value;
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if ( !(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) )
    {
        document.getElementById('email').focus();
        document.getElementById('emptymail').innerHTML = "Use your username, not email to login";
        return;
    }

    document.forms["formu"].submit();

}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Okay, tried it. Isn't working. Do I need anything to `<input class="xlarge" id="email" name="email" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" /><div id="emptymail"></div>` ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. What isn't working?

Comment: Check this screenshot, is the code right http://i.imgur.com/i7oalBW.png

Comment: And well, i put an email address in the field to try it out, but it still submits

Comment: Try using Chromes debugger if you are having trouble.
http://www.nsbasic.com/app/tutorials/TT10.htm

Comment: Of course it does. Noting stops the submit... you put the code that checks for email AFTER the code that submits the form...
I think you might need a basic programming course.

Comment: So the Javascript which u wrote, goes underneath the submit button?

Comment: Updated my answer to a complete solution that should work.

Comment: It stil does the same, i still can enter an email and press submit, which then takes me to the next page

Comment: There should have been an ! before the test. Updating.